# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'free_symbols' when usins latex2sympy

Tags: latex, sympy, symbolic-math

I want to define a program that extracts the variables of an equation in latex, but sometimes I get an error and I don't know why this happens.

This the code I have done:

```
from sympy import sympify, diff, sqrt, latex, simplify, symbols
from latex2sympy2 import latex2sympy

def variables(latex_funcion):
    # Convertir la función en formato LaTeX a una expresión simbólica
    funcion_simbolica = latex2sympy(latex_funcion)

    # Obtener las variables de la expresión
    variables = funcion_simbolica.free_symbols
    return variables
latex_funcion1 = r'\frac{x}{y}'
latex_funcion2 = r'I=m r_{e j e}^2\left(\frac{g}{b}-1\right)'
variables1 = variables(latex_funcion1)
print(variables1)
variables2 = variables(latex_funcion2)
print(variables2)
```

I expect to exctract the variables of the `latex_funcion2` or at least know why this happen and ensure to not use that format

Comment: did you look at `funcion_simbolica` when you have that problem?

Comment: It provide this output wich I dón't understand: <function variables at 0x0000024E738C8CC0>
[Eq(m, -I*b/(r_{eje}**2*(b - g))), Eq(b, g*m*r_{eje}**2/(m*r_{eje}**2 + I)), Eq(r_{eje}, -sqrt(-I*b/(m*(b - g)))), Eq(r_{eje}, sqrt(-I*b/(m*(b - g)))), Eq(g, b + I*b/(m*r_{eje}**2))]
<function variables at 0x0000024E738C8CC0>